# Using Meteors findOne() sort by date only if geolocation condition is met

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to figure out the best way to findOne() and sort a collection by date, but only if the latitude and longitude is less than 5km away.

Right now im storing the geolocation of the user in a variable, when the user makes a post the geolocation is saved in the collection with the message. I'm using the Euclidean distance formula in a javascript function to calculate the distance between the messages and user viewing the website, and I'll need this to work on the client.

So lets say the users geolocation is:

```
Location.setMockLocation({
   latitude: 44,
   longitude: 121
});
```

I would then insert the message with the geolocation in the collection.

What's the best way to retrieve it ONLY if the users geolocation and messages geolocation is closer than 5km BUT still sort by date inserted.

```
Messages.findOne({}, { sort: { date: -1} });
```

Should I use $near?

```
 getMessage: function(){
    return Messages.find({
        loca: {
            $near : { 
                $geometry : { 
                    type : "Point" ,
                    coordinates : [Session.get('userLng'),Session.get('userLat')]
                },
                $maxDistance: 5
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But how would I also make sure its sorted by date first

Comment: Are you storing any data in database ?

Comment: Yes the message with the geolocation is being stored to a database collection called 'Messages'

Comment: Sorry typo I means date not data